# Does hasNextInt(); method in java has default value?

Tags: java

I am new to java programming, and i am trying to learn about different methods available in Scanner class, i came to **hasNextInt();** method,does this method has any default values,either true or false,since in the code, first compiler prints **"Enter your year of birth:"**,then compiler moves to next Line that is , **boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();**,at this point what compiler will do since it has no input?.

This code is working fine,for example if i give invalid input to yearOfBirth ,like **"abc"** it prints **"Unable to parse year of birth."**,and when i give valid integer input it works fine too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your year of birth:");

    boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();

    if(hasNextInt) {
        int yearOfBirth = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); // handle next line character (enter key)

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        int age = 2018 - yearOfBirth;

        if(age >= 0 && age <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ", and you are " + age + " years old.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid year of birth");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to parse year of birth.");
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: "at this point what compiler will do since it has no input?.". The documentation says ["returns true **if and only if** this scanner's next token **is a valid int value**"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--)

Comment: @Aomine,then will it skip the if condition given afterward **if(hasNextInt()){} ?

Comment: hasNextInt() blocks until the next token is available (or the stream is closed). Then, if the next token is a valid int, it returns true, otherwise it returns false. The compiler has nothing to do with any of that: the compiler compiles the Java to byte-code. It doesn't eecute the methods in the byte-code.

Comment: @JB Nizet , you said it waits until the next token is recieved, but in above code to recieve the next token it has to pass that if condition?, so can you explain the control flow of program?

Comment: No, it doesn't. the runtime can only tell that the condition in the if block is true once hasNextInt() has executed and returned a value. That can take 2 years if nothing is enetered for 2 years.

Comment: This Line `if(hasNextInt)` checks if the boolean condition `hasNextInt` is true if it is then it moves on to execute the code in the if...block.The next line `int yearOfBirth = scanner.nextInt();` assigns the last integer value read by the scanner to the variable `yearOfBirth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.

In other words, the `hasNextInt` method will block (wait) if necessary until input is received.

Comment: ,,then will it skip the if condition given afterward **if(hasNextInt()){} ?

Comment: Depends.  If, after waiting, the next input is an integer, then it will enter that `if` block.  If it is something else, then it will enter the `else` block.

Comment: to get the next input,the if condition has to be true,then only it will take input,because taking input is inside the if block.

Comment: if `hasNextInt` returns false, it does nothing but create a blank line

Comment: @preciousbetine, i can't understand the flow of the program,what happens when compiler sees the line **boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();**?it waits for the input, but for that if condition has to be true.

Comment: @Ayush when the compiler sees that line, it checks if it's valid Java code, and if it is, it compiles it to byte-code. If not, it generates an error. You're confusing **compiling** code, with **running** code. When the code **executes**, it  blocks, doing nothing until the next token is available, when it is, if it's an int, the variable is initialized to true, otherwise, it initializes it to false. Just like you would do if you were asked "tell me the gender of the next person in the queue: you would wait until someone is in the queue, and when there is someone, you would tell male or female.